# the error is in space.photos.map in the map section

Tags: flutter, dart

children:
space.photos.map((item) {
return Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(
left: 24,
),
child: ClipRRect(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
child: Image.network(
item,
width: 110,
height: 88,
fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
),
);
}).toList()

Comment: Hi Ivan, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question to provide more clarity about what you are seeking help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.get()` takes a Uri as its argument and not a string. Correct way: `http.get(Uri.parse('https://bwa-cozy.herokuapp.com/recommended-spaces'));`